# GIT. Возврат изменений в отдельном файле отдельного коммита

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

Есть такая ситуация: нужно удалить определенные изменения из проекта. Все эти изменения были сделаны одним коммитом. Затем было ещё коммиты, несколько из которых затрагивали измененные файлы (2 файла из 9)
Можно ли при помощи гита откатить только изменения первого коммита в этих файлах?

Comment: "Одной кнопкой" не знаю как. Но смысл такой: git revert no-commit, коммитим те файлы которые нужно ревертнуть, остальные откатываем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git revert -n 1234567 // плохой коммит
git commit path/to/file -m 'reverted blahblah' // файл который нужно ревертнуть
git reset --hard Head // остальное нам не надо
```

Смысл такой:
1. ревертим плохой коммит, но не коммитим отменяющие изменения.
2. Коммитим отменяющие изменения в нужных файлах
3. Сбрасываем все (то есть файлы, которые не хотим менять) к состоянию последнего коммита (коммита из пункта 2).

Я делаю так, в любом gui это пара кликов. Возможно есть более изящные способы.

Comment: А можно ли как то вернуть изменения только коммита, который хотим откатить и оставить все изменения, которые были после коммита, изменения которого откатываем?

Comment: @GrodasNet, а текущий способ не так работает?) Revert ревертит изменения одного коммита, а не все дерево.